# Gallery in jQuery with list

Tags: jquery, list, redirect, location, gallery

I was looking for some gallery with previous/next buttons, and i found it. I have code:

```
var speed = 0;
$('#mask-gallery, #gallery li').width($('#slider').width());    
$('#gallery').width($('#slider').width() * $('#gallery li').length);
$('#mask-gallery, #gallery li').height($('#slider').height());
$('#gallery li:first').addClass('selected');

$('#btn-next, #gallery').click(function () {
 newsscoller(0);    
 return false;
});

$('#btn-prev').click(function () {
 newsscoller(1);    
 return false;
});

function newsscoller(prev) {
    var current_image = $('#gallery li.selected').length ? $('#gallery li.selected') : $('#gallery li:first');
    if (prev) {
        var next_image = (current_image.prev().length) ? current_image.prev() : $('#gallery li:last');
    } else {
        var next_image = (current_image.next().length) ? current_image.next() : $('#gallery li:first');
    }

    $('#gallery li').removeClass('selected');
    next_image.addClass('selected');
    $('#mask-gallery').scrollTo(next_image, 250);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/R27FS/

And i have one question. Anybody have idea how it script can redirect user for the defined page (location.href = '';) after last slide?

Thanks for replies!

Comment: noooooo never redirect on last slide! there's no gallery with such functionality! rather add a click or create a button on the last slide and make it clickable! think about users, if you surprise them (badly) they'll never come back again. I'm one of them.

Comment: I agree, no one would want that.  Almost as bad as background music!

Comment: all the same I will be grateful for some solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to set the 'next' link to an actual location on the last slide. And then `return true;` on the `click` event if `href!="#"`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R27FS/3/)**

```
var speed = 0;
$('#mask-gallery, #gallery li').width($('#slider').width());
$('#gallery').width($('#slider').width() * $('#gallery li').length);
$('#mask-gallery, #gallery li').height($('#slider').height());
$('#gallery li:first').addClass('selected');

$('#btn-next, #gallery').click(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (href != "#" && href != "") return true;
    newsscoller(0);
    return false;
});

$('#btn-prev').click(function () {
    newsscoller(1);
    return false;
});

function newsscoller(prev) {
    var current_image = $('#gallery li.selected').length ? $('#gallery li.selected') : $('#gallery li:first');
    var next_image;
    $("#btn-next").attr("href", "#");
    if (prev) {
        next_image = (current_image.prev().length) ? current_image.prev() : $('#gallery li:last');
    } else {
        if (current_image.next().length) {
            next_image = current_image.next();
        }
        if (!next_image.next().length) {
            $("#btn-next").attr("href", "http://www.google.com");
            //'target' required for it to work in jsFiddle b/c of 
            //iframe, remove in your code.
            $("#btn-next").attr("target", "_blank");
        }
    }

    $('#gallery li').removeClass('selected');
    next_image.addClass('selected');
    $('#mask-gallery').scrollTo(next_image, 250);
}
```